# Bind internal element name of custom UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a custom UserControl inside another one:

```
<Grid ....>
    <Contentcontrol Name="ContentPresenter" />
    <Button Content="NextButton" />
</Grid>
```

I set my `ContentPresentr` content to a custom user control that has some `TextBox`. I want this first button to be enabled/disabled depending if the `TextBox` inside the second user control has any value or not.

This is my try:

```
<UserControl ....>
    <Contentcontrol Name="ContentPresenter" />
    <Button Content="NextButton" >
     <Button.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
               <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                 <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type view:UsersUcAddStep0}}, ElementName=TextBoxName}" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

ContentControl.xaml (summarized, too large):

```
<UserControl x:Class="View.UsersUcAddStep0"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Name="AddUserInfo" 
         Loaded="UsersUcAddStep0_OnLoaded"
         Unloaded="OnUnloaded">
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Name="TextBoxName" 
                     Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight, 
                     Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}, ConverterParameter=Int32.Parse(values[0]) / 2.5}"
                     Style="{DynamicResource InnerTextBox}" 
                     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}" 
                     LostFocus="TextBox_OnLostFocus"
                     PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_OnPreviewKeyDown"
                     model:TextBoxBehavior.SelectAllTextOnFocus="True">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Name" Source="{StaticResource UserInformation}" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But it doesn't compile at all. Anybody has any idea on how to make this binding?

Comment: Assuming that your `TextBox`'es `Text` property is bound to a view model property, you could bind your `Button`'s `IsEnabled` property to a view model property: either to the text property directly (with a converter) or to a custom `bool` property that indicates whether the text property is empty or not.

Comment: I'm trying to bind to Text view model property, but with no luck...

Comment: Why do you need this user control? Id does only contain a `TextBox`. You only need to create an `UserControl` if you want to change the functionality of existing ones. In this case, I can't see anything that could point out that. I suggest you to use simple XAML markup rather than creating custom controls. Are you coming from the Windows Forms world?

Comment: I wrote: reduced as it's really big... I need it. Here I copied only the involved code, but the UserControl contains more than 500 lines. And no, I mostly use WPF.